# Inserting csv files into Hive table dynamically

Tags: hive

There is a folder named "Sample" which contains n number of csv files. How to load all the csv files into Hive table dynamically?

For normal insert we use

```
load data inpath "file1.csv" into table Person;
```

With out hardcoding, can it be done for all the files??

Answer (score 0):

You just need to pass in the directory name like:

```
load data inpath "/directory/name/here" into table Person;
```

Quoting the manual :

> *filepath* can refer to a file (in which case Hive will move the file
>   into the table) or it can be a directory (in which case Hive will move
>   all the files within that directory into the table). In either case,
>   *filepath* addresses a set of files.

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DML